# ¿Cómo funciona esta función que crea una lista enlazada para cualquier cadena de entorno?

Tags: c, lista, punteros, manejo-de-memoria

Mi confusión comienza en `pathNode = malloc(sizeof(Node))`  y termina en `return (head);`

**Primero**, no entiendo por qué esta función aloja el tamaño de una variable tipo llamada "Node", luego almacena esa información en una variable llamada `pathNode`, y justo después de eso hay una `declaración SI` que se ejecuta en caso de que `pathNode` sea un valor `NULL`, quiero decir, *¿cómo podría ser eso posible si la variable de tipo "Node" es fija (al menos inicialmente)*?

**Segundo**, Entiendo que la función `strtok` se usa para dividir una cadena usando un delimitador, que en este caso es `:`. También sé que el operador de flecha `->` se usa para acceder a elementos en `Estructuras`.

Pero luego, las siguientes líneas de código `pathNode-> str = token;` y `pathNode-> next = head;` son como, algún tipo de *declaración de variable invertida*, lo que hace que la sintaxis me parezca extraña, y estas variables `str` y `next` no se declararon como en el caso de los punteros, ¿no es eso necesario?

Y **finalmente**, está el ciclo while, que supongo que se ejecutará hasta que encuentre el elemento `\0` al final de la cadena `pathCopy`. Sin embargo, nuevamente existe el uso de `pathNode = malloc (sizeof (Node));` , `pathNode-> str = token;` y `pathNode-> next = head;`, devolviéndome a la confusión anterior ...

El código es el siguiente:

```
    typedef struct Node
    {
         char *str;
         struct Node *next;

    } Node;

    Node *_getdir(char *path, char **pathCopy)
    {
        char *token = NULL;
        Node *head;
        Node *pathNode;


    if (path == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    *pathCopy = strdup(path); 

    head = NULL;
    pathNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (pathNode == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    token = strtok(*pathCopy,  ":");
    pathNode->str = token;
    pathNode->next = head;
    head = pathNode;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        if (token == NULL) 
            break;
        pathNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (pathNode == NULL)
            return (NULL);
        pathNode->str = token;
        pathNode->next = head;
        head = pathNode;
    }
    return (head);

    }
    path = "/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
    char *pathCopy = NULL;
    pathDirs = _getdir(path, pathCopy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos con tus dudas de una en una:

- **Primera**. `malloc()` se ocupa de buscar una zona de bytes contiguos que esté libre en una parte de la memoria denominada *heap*. Lo que le pasas como parámetro es simplemente cuántos bytes quieres (en este caso los necesarios para albergar una estructura de tipo `Node`). Si `malloc()` encuentra una zona libre de ese tamaño, te retorna un puntero a la misma. Si no puede encontrarla (porque todo el *heap* esté ocupado o muy fragmentado y no es posible encontrar esa cantidad de bytes *contigua*), retorna `NULL`.

  De modo que la comprobación de `NULL` es lo típico que se hace justo tras un `malloc()`, pues puede darse el caso de que no haya memoria para crear un nuevo `Node`.
- **Segunda** Las "variables" (como tú las llamas) `str` y `next` son en realidad campos de una estructura. La sintaxis C `puntero->campo` es lo mismo que `(*puntero).campo`. Es decir, se espera que `puntero` apunte a una estructura y que `campo` sea el nombre de un campo de dicha estructura.

  En tu caso `pathNode` es un puntero a `Node`. Al principio del código puede verse cómo se declara este tipo:

  ```
  typedef struct Node
  {
       char *str;
       struct Node *next;

  } Node;
  ```

  y vemos que efectivamente tiene los campos `str` y `next`.
- **Tercera**. Esta duda está relacionada con cómo funciona `strtok()`, que tiene una interfaz ciertamente extraña. La primera vez que se llame a `strtok()` debes pasarle un puntero a una cadena como primer parámetro (y como segundo otra cadena que será la que se usará para trocear). En cambio, *en todas las iteraciones siguientes* hay que pasarle `NULL` como primer parámetro. Eso le dice a `strtok()` que sigue trabajando con la cadena anterior y que te retorne *el token siguiente* (al que había retornado la vez anterior). Cuando ya no hay más tokens retorna `NULL`.

  Por tanto el bucle while está iterando por todos los trozos que resultan de dividir la cadena a que apunta `pathCopy` usando como divisor `":"`

Comment: Hola @abulafia, disculpa mi error, acabo de agregar al principio del código, el tipo de estructura a la cual se refiere con "Node", espero puedas volver a revisarla, un saludo!

Comment: Hola. Gracias por añadir ese código. En realidad corrobora lo que yo ya decía en mi respuesta, y es que `str` y `next` son dos campos de la estructura `Node`. He editado la respuesta para reflejarlo mejor. ¿Ha aclarado esto tus dudas?

Comment: Creo que sí, de momento, te daré el chulo ✓ a ti por lo rápido que fuiste, sí vuelvo a confundirme, simplemente volveré a preguntar jeje.